# set svm classifier to HOG detector

Tags: c++, opencv, svm

I work on training my own SVM. First I want is train it to detect people and compare result  with SVM which is implement in opencv. After the training SVM looks fine (I create xml file to check) but I can't  set svm detector to HOG.

Here is how i train and save my svm:

```
std::cout << "Entering trainAndSave" << std::endl;

cv::Ptr<cv::ml::SVM> svm = cv::ml::SVM::create();
svm->setType(cv::ml::SVM::C_SVC);
svm->setKernel(cv::ml::SVM::RBF);
std::cout << "Creating SVM pointer successfull" << std::endl;

cv::Ptr<cv::ml::TrainData> tData = cv::ml::TrainData::create(trainingData, cv::ml::SampleTypes::ROW_SAMPLE, labels);

std::clog << "Wait until training will get finish! This may take a few minutes...";
svm->trainAuto(tData);
std::clog << "...[done]" << std::endl;
std::cout << "trainAuto successfull" << std::endl;

svm->save(filename);
std::cout << "saving to file successfull" << std::endl;
```

I think it's done correctly and the problem is how I get support vector and set smv detector to HOG:

```
    cv::Ptr<cv::ml::SVM> svm = cv::ml::SVM::load(filename);
    // get support vectors
    cv::Mat supportVectors = svm->getSupportVectors();
    const int supportVectorsTotal = supportVectors.rows;

    // get the decision function
    cv::Mat alpha, sVidx;
    double rho = svm->getDecisionFunction(0, alpha, sVidx);

    CV_Assert(alpha.total() == 1 && sVidx.total() == 1 && supportVectorsTotal == 1);
    CV_Assert((alpha.type() == CV_64F && alpha.at<double>(0) == 1.) ||
        (alpha.type() == CV_32F && alpha.at<float>(0) == 1.f));
    CV_Assert(supportVectors.type() == CV_32F);

    std::vector<float> svmDetector(supportVectors.cols + 1);
    memcpy(&svmDetector[0], supportVectors.ptr(), supportVectors.cols * sizeof(svmDetector[0]));
    svmDetector[supportVectors.cols] = (float)-rho;

    hog.setSVMDetector(svmDetector);
```

After when svm is load I get error in this line:

```
        CV_Assert(alpha.total() == 1 && sVidx.total() == 1 && supportVectorsTotal == 1);
```

[error looks like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uvjH7.png)

I really don't know where the problem is. I will be very grateful for all the advice.

Answer (score 0):

This error is because, you have instance the HOG detector before `setSVMDetector`, with the same params that you computed HOG descriptors for create your svm classifier.

For example, put your params values

```
 HOGDescriptor hog;
 hog.winSize = Size(256,256);
 hog.blockSize = Size(128,128);
 hog.blockStride = Size(64,64);
 hog.cellSize = Size(32,32);
 hog.nbins =9;
```

then, run again.